# Can I display Image in alt attribute if an image fails to load

Tags: html, css

```
<img src="#" alt="Sorry the image could not be displayed.">
```

In the above code I want display an image in alt instead of text.In this way I want to display my site logo as image if it is unable to connect to internet.

Update:I am developing android application using Phonegap.

Comment: If there is no internet, how are they meant to load the second image?

Comment: try using script with `onerror` event handler

Comment: This is not how `alt` is intended to be used: `alt attributes must contain text that together convey the purpose of the link or button` from http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/img

Comment: If there is no internet, how are people meant to load your site?

Comment: No, this isn't possible; the `alt` attribute is meant to contain text to convey the image's meaning/intent in the event the image doesn't load. If the image couldn't load, why would you expect any image in an attribute to load?

Comment: Loading second image without connecting to internet is silly.I was just trying to give some example.Sorry for that.Actually I am working on Android application using phonegap which means I want to load an image which is inside my app  in case it is unable to load an image from internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments - If your user doesn't have an internet connection, there's no way they can load a new image.  However, if it's of any use to you and you wanted to load in placeholders for whatever reason.

You could do something like this with jQuery

I've set up a basic fiddle for you which is easy enough to understand.

**Image With # Src**

```
<img src="#" alt="no image" />
```

**Variables to find # Src and to replace with placeholder**

```
var noSrc = '#';
var noImg = 'http://placehold.it/400x500';
$('img[src="' + noSrc + '"]').attr('src', noImg);
```

Just change the path of  the **noImg** variable to whatever your image path will be.

**Working Example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tpMvL/)**

```
<img src="#" alt="no image" />
$('img[src="#"]').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/400x500');
```

**Example without Variables: [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/tpMvL/1/)**